# Does powering NodeMCU with 3.3 V also power USB-UART module?

Tags: esp8266, power-consumption, power-sources

I want to power my nodemcu module with 3.3 V.

Does powering it with 3.3 V also power USB-UART module?

If so I do not want this as it eats the battery.

[image]

Comment: What is the version of you NodeMCU?

Comment: @BenceKaulics 2nd generation / v1.0 / V2

Comment: if you want low power, you really need to get away from modules and especially devkits.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the [schematic of the v1.0 NodeMCU](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-devkit-v1.0/blob/master/NODEMCU_DEVKIT_V1.0.PDF) shows that the 3.3 V bus is directly connected to the CP2102 chip.

[image]

You have two possibilities:

1. Cut the 3.3 V trace on the PCB before the CP2102 chip. Not recommended as you will disable your programming interface and would be hard to restore it.
2. The reset pin (RST) pin of the CP2102 is floating, you can try to pull it down to GND and keep the chip in reset, to see if that makes it any better.

Comment: But in deepsleep mode when  the current is measured with a multimeter it is 0.000

Comment: Are you sure that you are measuring it correctly? 0.000 seems strange also it means nothing without units.

Comment: Sorry it is showing 0.00

Comment: And is it kA, A, or uA it matters a lot? 0.00 without SI unit is just a number and nothing else.

Comment: 0.00 amperes using multimeter

Comment: @ACSreedharReddy change your multimeter's measurement range to micro amps and repeat the measurement. Also I think you got the answers regarding the USB-UART module. For further decreasing the consumption you already have an other open [question](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/3218/nodemcu-connected-with-batteries-stopped-working-after-2-hours).

Comment: Note that cutting the power to an IC is likely a data sheet violation unless explicitly allowed, ie, if the input voltage range is not relative to Vdd.  If any of the signals to it are high, you may end up re-powering it through the protection diodes.

Comment: @ChrisStratton True, true. By the way the input voltage range is not relative to VDD. Also there is a part in the datasheet "In  addition,  if  VDD  or  REGIN  may  be  unpowered  while  VBUS  is  5 V,  a  resistor divider  (...)  shown  in  Note 1 of  Figure 8  is  required  to  meet  the absolute maximum voltage on VBUS specification in Table 2.". Based on this I think it is fine if VDD and REGIN are unpowered, nevertheless it was a hasty statement from me and if someone choose to give up on the UART-USB module it is better to entirely remove it from the board.

Comment: Yes, looks like it's a 3v3 part with 5v tolerant I/O.  That input structure can often deal with an I/O voltage even in the complete absence of supply.  So probably OK in this case.